# Модификатор доступа protected и default не очень понятно

Tags: java

Не очень понимаю отличие модификаторa доступа protected и default.
Если ничего не указывать?

Comment: Ниже вроде описали, а что именно не понятно?

Answer (score 3):

Если ничего не указывать, тогда будет стоять видимость по умолчанию - т.е. default.

Protected -  "защищенный" - это видимость в границах пакета и видимость для классов-наследников. Можно сказать, что protected = default + наследование.

Answer (score 1):

«Модификатор по умолчанию».

Если переменная или метод не помечены никаким модификатором, то считается, что они помечены «модификатором по умолчанию». Переменные и методы с таким модификатором видны всем классам пакета, в котором они объявлены, и только им. Этот модификатор еще называют «package» или «package private», намекая, что доступ к переменным и методам открыт для всего пакета, в котором находится их класс

Модификатор «protected».

Этот уровень доступа чуть шире, чем package. К переменной, методу или классу, помеченному модификатором protected, можно обращаться из его же пакета (как package), но еще из всех классов, унаследованных от текущего.